# variables set inside jQuery.getJSON callback don't retain their value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

In my website, I use a category tree stored as a JSON object in the file "categories.json". It's value is stored as the property "tree" of an object named "category", along with some methods for accessing it. This is part of the code:

```
var category = {

    tree: {},

    // loads the tree into memory
    loadTree: function() {
        $.getJSON("categories.json", function(data) {
            this.tree = data;
            console.log("Tree loaded");
        });
    },

    // Returns an array with the children of a node
    getChildren: function(name) {
        return this.tree[name].children;
    }

    ...
}
```

I understand that since getJSON is an asynchronous function, the effects of the callback that I passed as an argument won't take place immediately. However, even after the "Tree loaded" message has been shown, whenever I access the category.tree object (ie. calling category.getChildren() and printing the result), it is empty.

Comment: `return this.tree[name].children;`  need to be `return category.tree[name].children;`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Are you sure? Since `category` is the base object, I'd say `return category.tree[name].children`. `tree` is undefined.

Comment: oh yes. thanks for telling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` does not refer to anything. You are inside the `category` object, therefore, you have to refer it.

`this` would make sense if you were inside a Class instance, but this is just a regular object.

```js
var category = {

    tree: {},

    // loads the tree into memory
    loadTree: function() {
        category.tree = { foo : "bar" }
    },

    // Returns an array with the children of a node
    getChildren: function(name) {
        return category.tree
    }

}

category.loadTree()
console.log( category.getChildren() ) // { foo : "bar" }
```

Same thing with a Class, where using `this` makes sense :

```js
class Category {

 constructor(){
      this.tree = {} 
 }
 
    // loads the tree into memory
    loadTree() {
        this.tree = { foo : "bar" }
    }

    // Returns an array with the children of a node
    getChildren(name) {
        return this.tree
    }

}

const category = new Category()
category.loadTree()
console.log( category.getChildren() )
```